# Mixed Distribution of Binary and continuous

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I am trying to find the conditional distribution of a binary variable $Y_2$ and a continuous random variable $Y_1$. As a hint the professor proposed the introduction of a latent variable $W$ such that $Y_2=1$ if $W>0$ and $Y_2=0$ if $W\le0$. We are assuming that $Y_1\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1)$ and $W\sim N(\mu_w, \sigma_w^2)$ such that $W|Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ here $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are place holders for the true
conditional parameters. We have been asked to show that $P(Y_2=1|Y_1)=\Phi(\frac{\mu}{\sigma})$. I believe that $P(Y_2=1,W>0|Y_1)=P(W>0|Y_1)$ then this follows easily. I believe this is true because of the relationship between $Y_2$ and $W$. That is, $P(W>0,Y_2=1)=P(W>0)$ but I don't know if the relationship still holds when I introduce the conditioning.